# Django rest framework serializer: required_fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

Is it possible to set required fields as a list inside serializer?
I don't want to override each fields with their type in the each line like this:

```py
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    date_start = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)
    date_end = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)
```

I just want to enumerate the names of fields

```py
class CampaignStepFirstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = (
            'name',
            'description',
            'date_start',
            'date_end',
        )
        required_fields = fields
```

Comment: yes, this is DRF

Answer (score 4):

If the model field was instantiated with `null=True` or `blank=True`, or if the model field has a default value, the Serializer will automatically set the corresponding field as `required=False`.  (See the source of [`rest_framework.utils.field_mapping.get_field_kwargs`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0d5250cffada2ac250e24407953d4862d04d3dae/rest_framework/utils/field_mapping.py#L104)).

If you need to override this behavior, you can do this:

```py
class CampaignStepFirstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = (
            'name',
            'description',
            'date_start',
            'date_end',
        )

        # 1st option. If some fields are required
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {'required': True},
            'description': {'required': True},
            'date_start': {'required': True},
            'date_end': {'required': True},
        }

        # 2nd option. If all the fields are required:
        extra_kwargs = {i:{'required': True} for i in fields}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option in DRF. The closest you can get with `Meta` is `extra_kwargs` (assuming you're using `serializers.ModelSerializer`), with mentioning the field names separately with values being a dict with `{'required': True}`. But that would be more work than explicitly mentioning `required=True` while initializing the fields.

---

You can get what you want with a tiny bit of extension to the `get_fields` method of `serializers.Serializers` and any sublclass (e.g. `serializers.ModelSerializer`):

```
class CampaignStepFirstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def get_fields(self):

        fields = super().get_fields()

        try:
            required_fields = self.Meta.required_fields
        except AttributeError:
            return fields

        if not isinstance(required_fields, (list, tuple)):
            raise TypeError(
                'The value of `Meta.required_fields` option must be a list or tuple.'
            )

        for field_name in required_fields:
            try:
                field = fields[field_name]
            except KeyError:
                continue

            if (
                    not field.read_only and
                    field.default is serializers.empty
            ):
                field.required = True
                fields[field_name] = field

        return fields

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = (
            'name',
            'description',
            'date_start',
            'date_end',
        )
        required_fields = fields
```

As shown, in the `Meta` class of the serializer class, you can define the `required_fields` option and those fields will be made as `required` if they are not `read_only` and doesn't have a default.

One caveat of this is that, if you have some field defined explicitly on serializer with `required=False`, and also mentioned the field in `Meta.required_fields`, the `__repr__` will show the `required=False` (for example, when you'll be checking `<serializer_instance>.fields`). [`serializers.Field.__repr__` is defined such that the initial arguments used in the creation of a field are shown as-is](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L657). The constructor (`Field.__new__`) keeps a `_kwargs` attribute to preserve the initial arguments.

This applies to all the explicitly declared fields (the metaclass `serializers.SerailizerMetaclass` sets `_declared_fields` attribute on the serializer class) so using `read_only_fields`/`write_only_fields`/`extra_kwargs` `Meta` options also don't impact the representation.

If you want, you can override the `__repr__` of the field to change this but I don't think you should do so as that will break consistency with the rest of the design.